# Android Studio "Cannot resolve class com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton" after dependencies added

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to implement Twitter login within my Android Studio app, but it is not recognizing the TwitterLoginButton in my xml file. I have added the following to my `build.gradle (:app)`:

```
dependencies{
    ...
    compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.3.0'
    compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-ui:3.3.0'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.1"
}
```

Added the following to `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And then added the following to my `twitter_login.xml` file

```
<com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="user Login"
    android:id="@+id/btnTwitterLogin"
    android:enabled="true"/>
```

However, the layout addition is showing red with the following error message:

```
Cannot resolve class com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton
```

Is there something more I need to add in order to make this work? I recently did something similar with Facebook and it worked immediately. I am having trouble understanding why Twitter is not doing the same.

** I have also already created an app with Twitter Dev and been approved, set up the Callback/Website URLS, and provided my API Key and Secret to Firebase and my app in `strings.xml`

[TwitterLoginButton Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgEFt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i can recommand:
1 - Sync Gradle file to make sure your dependencies are installed.
2 - If the problem persists, Rebuild your project (Android Studio File menu-> Build-> Rebuild Project).
3 - if it still presists, then Add this:
`compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.3.0') {transitive = true;}`